# Ruby ASCII-8BIT encoding equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to convert the following code from ruby to C#:

```
open(file_path, ’rb’) do |doc|
    response = RestClient::Request.execute :method => :post,
                 :url => "http://something.com",
                 :payload => {
                 :document => doc
                 }
```

my understanding is this will read a file in binary in ASCII-8BIT as per the following documentation:

```
"b"  Binary file mode
     Suppresses EOL <-> CRLF conversion on Windows. And
     sets external encoding to ASCII-8BIT unless explicitly
     specified.
```

So trying to replicate this example code in C# I have written:

```
string myString;
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(????);

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\sample1page.pdf", FileMode.Open))
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs, enc))
        {
            byte[] bin = br.ReadBytes(System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
            myString = enc.GetString(bin);
        }
```

So the question is what encoding number do I need to do markerd by ???? is to do the equivalent ASCII-8BIT that works in ruby

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "ASCII-8BIT"? There are many 8-bit "ASCII extensions" which are different.

Comment: I think thats where i am confused but thats whats in the ruby documentation found here:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/IO.html#method-c-new

Comment: Since this code just POSTs file to api endpoint - I doubt you need to do anything with encodings. Just read file (for example with `File.ReadAllBytes`) and post it. You do not need to treat that file as string.

Comment: ASCII-8BIT is not really an encoding in Ruby. Rather, it denotes the *absence* of an encoding. (It has an alias "BINARY" that is probably more descriptive.) The equivalent to a Ruby `String` with an `Encoding` of ASCII-8BIT in C♯ would be something like a `byte[]`.